# php artisan make:controller RegistrationController --resourse -- model=Registration The "--resourse" option does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-artisan

i was trying to create a controller for my student registration crud app when i got an error message saying "--resource" option does not exist

Answer (score 1):

php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource

please use that comand its resour(c)e not resour(s)e use C not S